# Trying to move MBR to another disk using linux, or something... end result, dual linux and windows. Complicated, please read

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Allright, so as is says in the title, I'm not an expert. So I'm going to explain everything that I've done, and what I'm trying to do.

One day, I decided to build a low-end gaming computer, for use with games such as World of Tanks. One of my budget cuts was to use a laptop's hard drive with its copy of Windows 7 as my OS. As you could imagine, it started complaining that "Windows isn't genuine" so, after some time, I bought a HDD for my desktop, and went about installing windows on it. Now, this is where it gets confusing...

I attempted to install windows using an .exe file my friend offered me on a flash drive. It appears to be the same thing that Microsoft offers on one of their recovery pages. The closest reference to what I have is found in [this forum.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-do-i-run-downloaded-windows-7-exe-installation/31758d2d-f80e-4465-9936-d5b553b73ea6?auth=1) (Hoping that helps, I can't describe it myself unless I were to paste the files here somehow.)

Before installing, I had to activate the new drive,and formatted it as a Primary, NTFS. During the installation, my computer rebooted several times. After the third reboot, I was presented a brand-new windows 7 desktop. The original Windows 7 data was preserved, although (obviously) not in this copy of the OS. (I can still boot to the "Laptop" windows 7 with everything on it.)

It's worth noting that to boot into this "new windows," I had to select "windows 7" from the windows bootloader. It showed two windows 7's, one was the one on the laptop drive, and the other (here's my noob skillz in coding explanation attempt) linked to the separate HDD.

Now, my master plan was to return the laptop drive back to the laptop. And that's what I did. Having some driver issues on the laptop, but that's to be expected, and dealt with later. I attempted to boot back into the separate HDD, only to find that there is not bootloader anymore.

So there's my obvious dilemma. I am currently running on the same built desktop, with an old HDD with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it, and that's where this comes in. I want to have this Linux OS dual booted with my Windows OS, but on separate HDD; I.e. Windows on HD1 and Ubuntu on HD2.

I've been looking for a way to modify the GRUB bootloader to allow me to select OS's and boot into windows, but (I'm assuming) because the MBR that allows me to boot to my "new windows" is on the laptop drive, Ubuntu's GRUB doesn't know there's an OS on my new drive. (Please remember, the Laptop drive is no longer plugged into the system. The system has the Ubuntu drive and the New Windows drive.)

**So, finally, here's my question:** What should I do? What can I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I would rather not use a windows 7 installation CD, just because I'd have to wait for it to get here, so anything info I can do with my current hardware is appreciated.)

I should note that I am not afraid to repeatedly open up my desktop and switch cables around; I am mostly limited by my 2 SATA data cables, currently shared between my 2 HDD's and my disk drive.

Comment: You cannot install windows and move the drive to another MOBO as windows will not allow that due to licensing restrictions. Only certain pre-release or trial versions will allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you moved your bootloader with that old laptop drive you put back into the laptop.

The one way I can think of to fix this is to CHROOT into your Ubuntu installation with a Live USB/CD. Then fix/install your bootloader.

**CHROOT:**

You will need to have a bootable CD or USB stick of Ubuntu to boot up your computer to. Select "Try Ubuntu before installing" to boot into the Live environment.

Once booted, start a Terminal window and type:

> sudo blkid | grep ext4

This will list all partitions (and I am hoping you didn't change the default installation suggestions) and the 'grep' filters out all entries without 'ext4' in the line. This should show you the harddrive/partition you need to mount.

Verify that it is the right partition/drive:

> df -Th | grep ext4

Next mount the partition into the Live environment:

> sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

.. where '/dev/sdXY' is the partition you found to be the right one in the blkid command.

Get the chroot environment ready by mounting all the necessary folders:

> for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

Once you have mounted the folders, you can chroot into the old desktop drive to fix your boot loader:

> sudo chroot /mnt

Now fix your bootloader by installing and updating it:

> grub-install /dev/sdX

Note that this is '/dev/sdX' and not '/dev/sdXY'. You don't want the bootloader in the partition, you want it on the drive (ie. /dev/sda).

Next, create the Grub menu:

> update-grub

If there are no errors, you should now have install your dual-booting GRUB menu. If everything seems ok, type 'exit' and reboot.

Comment: I'm a little pressed for time right now, but I'll be sure to try this all out later today!

The only foreseen complication I can think of is that my computer doesn't support the default Ubuntu desktop... I think it's unity 3d graphics or something, Radeon R7 250 card is to blame for sure... I'm currently running LXDE environment. Here's to hoping I can use a recovery terminal for all this... Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: Alright, my original boot disk, Which is old (12.04 LTS) isn't booting for some reason, I'm gonna create a USB bootable stick of Lubuntu 14.04 (14.04.3) and try my luck. I've had success creating bootable linux drives with the programs I am using, here's to hoping it doesn't fail me now.

Comment: Alright, finished doing everything up to "Update-grub" on your list. I have one minor concern... "Grub-install: warning: Sector 32 is already in use by the program 'FlexNet'; avoiding it. This software may cause boot or other problems in future. Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track. <enter> Installation finished. No error reported." That having been said, I didn't get a grub boot menu. Opened up my computer to make sure all cables are plugged in; no fault there. First command only gave /dev/sda1 as a result. Continued in next comment...

Comment: Using my motherboard BIOS, I was able to select each drive individually to boot to. Both redirected to my Ubuntu drive, because the Ubuntu login screen comes up. (I believe this means the BIOS doesn't recognize the new windows drive as a bootable drive.)

Comment: It could be that Windows also installed their boot partition on the old laptop drive. If that is the case, then you are in way more than a simple boot manager repair.

Comment: Also, the warning about "Sector 32 is already in use by the program 'FlexNet'" is regarding some DRM being installed into the boot track. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214517
That being said, Boot-Repair may still be an option for you to consider. Boot into Ubuntu and install/run that.

Comment: I actually found a thread and followed it's instructions after using chmod: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661254 This resulted in no warning after doing grub-install. However, no grub menu was displayed. I'm going to go do your commands again, can't remember if I ran grub-update the second time... Also, I used gparted to flag the new windows disc as "boot", but nothing happened. I still have access to the laptop drive, I can plug it up to the system if there's anything you can figure out...? I can recognize the separate HDDs by name in a terminal, if I need to.

Comment: Sounds like you might be on the right track. Without asking more questions about your setup we won't get much further here. But this is not a forum, so we best leave it here where it is. :)

Comment: @TreyWhite boot into ubuntu (no need to chroot if ubuntu works fine) and run the following command: `sudo update-grub` then, reboot. You need to run `sudo update-grub` after you add new operating systems to your system including new disks although, unless you used the same MOBO to install windows, windows probably won't work.

Comment: @mchid will do! Out of curiosity, the fact that linux is 32 bit and both other windows are 64 bit won't affect grub, will it?Also, not sure what you mean by "used the same MOBO to install windows..." In relation to linux, linux was installed on a differend MOBO than windows. The original windows was installed on a laptop motherboard, however both the laptop disk and the new disk were on the same board as the linux disk when new windows was installed. (Though it's worth mentioning linux disk was unplugged from mobo, due to me only having 2 SATA cables)

Comment: @TreyWhite it won't have any effect on grub. Linux and windows don't matter, however, windows needs to operate on the mobo it was installed on or you will probably have trouble getting it to run. So, if you installed the new windows on the linux computer, you won't be able to run that version of windows on another computer unless it is a certain rare trial version. Windows only licenses windows to run on one computer typically and they define "computer" as a motherboard.